# Unable to upload asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, upload

i recently uploaded an asp.net website to web server and the publish fails.
Now when i open the site on internet it says 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.i don't have permission to view this.. i tried filezilla to uplaod the files again. they uploaded but again the same message is displayed on browser.can you tell me where am i doing something wrong?i am using framework v4.0.

Comment: What does the server say? If you browse on the server is should give a little more detail. Seems evidently to do with permissions, so have you checked those in IIS and on the residing directories?

Comment: Just because you can FTP to the server, does not mean IIS has proper access.  Check the directory security in IIS manager.

Answer (score 1):

403 is a forbidden error.

Try checking the authentication settings for the website, you may need to enable Anonymous access in IIS for the website, otherwise it will just deny access.